# 512x512 icon problem in play console using phone

Tags: android, google-play-console

Am new at play console and am making use of android phone to upload to play store.
Am finding it difficult to upload an icon(512x512 cropped).
I don't know the app to use for icon making using android phone, or is it not possible  in
using android?

Comment: What image are you trying to upload? Does it meet Google's specifications?

Comment: @Wall D Are you on Linux? Use the `file` command to know the icon dimensions.